# The border is only working in chrome

Tags: html, css, asp.net, internet-explorer

I've got a GridView and I did the styling right in the aspx file.
It worked all fine in Chrome but I doesn't work in internet explorer.

```
       <style type="text/css">
   .GridView2 tbody tr th {
       border-top: thin solid white;
       border-left:thin solid white; 
       padding:5px;
       text-align:center;
   } 
       .GridView2 tbody tr td {
       border-top: thin solid white;
       border-left:thin solid white;
   }

    .GridView2 tbody tr:last-child td,.GridView2 tbody tr:last-child td,.GridView2 tbody tr:last-child td{
        border-bottom:thin solid white;
    }
    .GridView2 tbody tr th:last-child,.GridView2 tbody td:last-child{
        border-right:thin solid white;
    }
    .GridView2 tbody tr td{
       padding:5px;

    }

</style>
```

Can't I use one of these attributes? Or is there a problem inside the asp code?

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DataSource_struktur" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:CRM %>" SelectCommand="Select * from Table" > 
     </asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="5" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="Solid" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="25" DataSourceID="DataSource_struktur" 
    AllowSorting="True" ForeColor="#666666" CellSpacing="1" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,###,###}" 
    CaptionAlign="Left"  Width="400px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="GridView2"> 
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly=true HeaderText="Master Accounts" DataFormatString="{0:#,0} CMA" DataField="cma" SortExpression="cma" >
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        </asp:BoundField>

        <asp:BoundField ReadOnly=true DataField="sa_cnt" HeaderText="Service Accounts" SortExpression="sa_cnt" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
        <ControlStyle Font-Bold="False" />
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:BoundField>
   </Columns>

    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" ForeColor="#666666" />
    <PagerSettings Mode="Numeric" />
    <PagerStyle ForeColor="#11AAFF" Font-Names='"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Sans' 
        Font-Size="12px" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Top" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In your css you are writing style for the `GridView1 class`

```
.GridView1 tbody tr th {
```

And your gridview's `CssClass` attribute is GridView2

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ... CssClass="GridView2">
```

could that be the problem? Also, you have `BorderColor="Black"` in your gridview, and in your `CSS` all your border are White, if you are going to use the `CSS` then delete the gridview properties

Comment: sorry, I used the wrong one when i pasted it to stackoverflow

Comment: then update your post and add the images of Chrome vs IE, to see exactly what is what you want

Comment: I would add an image but I don't have enough reputation